# VBA calling procedure

Tags: arrays, excel, stored-procedures, vba

If I have an array or variable that I am passing from one procedure to the other is there any other way of doing it besides calling the next procedure at the end of each previous procedure? For a regular variable I can use a public variable but with an array its more tricky, especially if a 2+ dimensional array where you can only redim preserve the last dimension.

Here is what I have been doing

```
Option Explicit
Public strA As String, strIndex As String
```

---

```
Sub first_procedure (strA As String, strIndex As String) 
.
.
Call next_procedure (strA As String, strIndex As String) 

End Sub
```

---

```
sub next_procedure (strA As String, strIndex As String) 
.
.
.
Call third_procedure ((strA As String, strIndex As String) 
.
.
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not declare the array as Public?  If all you need to do is access it in several methods, one method would initialize it and the others wouldn't need to redim it at all because it will already have been filled.

Comment: A global variable (other than having a larger scope) is no different from a method-level one: a global array won't have any different behavior.  Having said that, as a "best practice" you should try not to declare any Globals you don't really *need* to.

Comment: Create a `Class`, thus [encapsulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) the data with the methods. That allows you to access the necessary data from within certain procedures / functions, and keep global scope clear of excessive variables.
You pointed out that use of a public variable is more tricky with an array, but didn't illustrate in the code.